# A word for "zone out frequently to think of your problems despite the happy occasion"

Tags: single-word-requests, expressions

When someone has a lot on their plate attends a party, a wedding or whatnot; and can't help zoning out frequently and becoming deep in thought to try finding solutions for their many problems. Is there a word/expression in English to refer to that situation? 
e.g. "On my wedding, he constantly kept 'X'. He was deep in debt, probably that was why". What would the word 'X' be?

Comment: For single word requests please include an example sentence with a blank.

Comment: It's "zofttoypdtho'.

Comment: @HotLicks - I could not find the word anywhere. Do you have any link?

Comment: https://english.stackexchange.com/questions/417955/a-word-for-zone-out-frequently-to-think-of-your-problems-despite-the-happy-occa

Comment: @HotLicks I laughed at your comment, I cursed in amazement when I saw you had an actual link, and then when I clicked the link I recursed.

Comment: He's not called @HotLicks for nothing.

Answer (score 3):

Not necessarily a perfect fit for your example sentence, but you could say that he was ***preoccupied:***

> [Preoccupied](https://www.merriam-webster.com/dictionary/preoccupied): 2a :lost in thought; also :absorbed in some preoccupation
>
> [Preoccupation](https://www.merriam-webster.com/dictionary/preoccupation): 2a :extreme or excessive concern with something
> <sub>*definitions from [Merriam-Webster.com](https://www.merriam-webster.com/dictionary/preoccupied)*</sub>

With a little rewording, it can definitely work:  "My friend seemed very preoccupied during my wedding.  Perhaps he was concerned about his gigantic gambling debts."

Answer (score 1):

"On my wedding, he constantly kept *withdrawing*. He was deep in debt, probably that was why".

Stated like this, there is a certain ambiguity for he might have kept physically leaving the room, or he might have repeatedly exhibited a withdrawn state.

So it is best to state, he was 'often withdrawn' in order to clearly indicate the state of being withdrawn.

[OED-3 :](http://www.oed.com/view/Entry/229630?redirectedFrom=withdrawn#eid)

> Withdrawn : In various senses of the vb.; sometimes in a purely static sense, **secluded**; also of mental state, **detached**. Also spec. in Psychol., characterized by **isolation and loss of contact with objective reality**.

[Merriam-Webster :](https://www.merriam-webster.com/dictionary/withdrawn)

> Withdrawn : socially detached and unresponsive :exhibiting withdrawal